# Function to turn an array of objects into an array of primitives, by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I currently need a JS function able to turn this :

```
[
    {
        prop1: 'val1',
        prop2: 'val2'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'val3',
        prop2: 'val4'
    },
    {
        prop1: 'val5',
        prop2: 'val6'
    }
]
```

Into this :

```
['val1', 'val3', 'val5'] // we only took each object's .prop1
```

As you may have noticed by this question's title, I'm not even sure of the right way to word this (English is not my native language).

As a consequence, it was kinda hard to find by Googling, so I wrote my own ; but I have the feeling there's some native JS function that would do the job. Is there ?

(For the record, here's what I wrote :)

```
function doSomethingByKey(objArr, key) {
    var result = [];

    for (i in objArr) {
        if (objArr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result.push(objArr[i][key]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over an array of objects and getting one key of each object is typically called as "plucking", though there are other names. In modern Javascript versions this can be trivially implemented with a map:

```
var arr  = [{ foo : 'bar', baz : 42 }, { foo : ... }, ...],
    foos = arr.map(function (obj) { return obj.foo; });
```

If you really want to abstract this into a function:

```
function pluck(arr, key) {
    return arr.map(function (obj) { return obj[key]; });
}

pluck(arr, 'foo');
```

If `hasOwnProperty` is a concern, your function is about as optimal as it gets already.

Comment: array.map doesn't seem to be working in my precise case, I think I'll just use my function indeed. Still chose (and upvoted) your answer because I think this is what I had in mind, and you learnt me of the word "plucking". Thanks ! :D

Comment: If you're still using a Javascript engine which does not have `Array.map`, you can shim it: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Thanks ! No, it's the data I'm using that must be wrong somewhere... But I looked it up and saw IE8 doesn't have this function, so I might need to shim it indeed. For the record, there's a simple implementation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility